# for loop generates illegal expression error

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

When I try to use iteration as below I get illegal expression error.

the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

url='https://search.newyorkfed.org/fomc-docs/search?advanced_search=true&fomc_document_type=minutes&text=&search_precision=All+Words&from_month=3&from_year=1951&to_month=4&to_year=2017&sort=Relevance&Search=Search' 

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get(url) time.sleep(5)
htmlSource = driver.page_source time.sleep(5) 
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/p[%s]/strong/a'%i): 
   print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do? Also edit your question to make it more readable

Comment: Andersson- so basically I am trying to capture all the href from the page. For a single request w/o iteration it works fine. But when I use iteration, it generates the error. I have also formatted code above.

Comment: What do you think this `p[%s]` supposed to be? Maybe you want to use something else instead of `%i`? Is it a simple typo?

Comment: Andersson - no that's not typo. I think so the urls looking at will have p[1], p[2]. which needs to iterate.

Comment: No. That's wrong assumption. You should iterate through static `list` of web elements while you're trying to update it on each iteration...

Comment: okay. Thanks. I tried to do that by defining a static variable too inside the loop. That did not work out as well. How would advise to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `XPath` expression `i` is not yet defined, so you cannot use it. Anyway `i in driver.find_elements_...()` should return a `WebElement`, so there is no sense using it in `XPath`

I don't know exactly why you use `p[%s]`, but if you want just to get all links in "Results", try:

```
for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//strong/a'): 
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Okay this helped. Thanks. I think I over thought.